# WPF: updating a canvas in a for loop

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, canvas

I'm having a problem with updating a canvas within a for loop in WPF. 
In my application I have data from stickfigures from a lot of frames and I want to draw the stickfigures of 2 different recordings next to each other. I know the drawing-function works, but I can't get my code to constantly update the canvas. I only get to see the stickfigure from the last frame. I know that for the other frames the stickfigures are being calculated but they aren't shown on the canvas.

I draw the stickfigures using PolyLine functions.

Here is the for loop that I use.

```
for (int i = 0; i < recording1.Count; i++)
        {
            skeletCanvas1.Children.Clear();
            skeletCanvas2.Children.Clear();

            skeletCanvas1.Children.Add(drawLine(points1((double[])recording1[i]), brush1));
            skeletCanvas1.Children.Add(drawLine(points2((double[])recording1[i]), brush1));
            skeletCanvas1.Children.Add(drawLine(points3((double[])recording1[i]), brush1));
            skeletCanvas1.Children.Add(drawLine(points4((double[])recording1[i]), brush1));
            skeletCanvas1.Children.Add(drawLine(points5((double[])recording1[i]), brush1));

            skeletCanvas2.Children.Add(drawLine(points1((double[])recording2[i]), brush2));
            skeletCanvas2.Children.Add(drawLine(points2((double[])recording2[i]), brush2));
            skeletCanvas2.Children.Add(drawLine(points3((double[])recording2[i]), brush2));
            skeletCanvas2.Children.Add(drawLine(points4((double[])recording2[i]), brush2));
            skeletCanvas2.Children.Add(drawLine(points5((double[])recording2[i]), brush2));

            skeletCanvas1.UpdateLayout();
            skeletCanvas2.UpdateLayout();

            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
        }
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You need a `BackgroundWorker`, doing `Thread.Sleep()` in the UI thread is going to freeze your application.

Comment: Please post a screenshot of what you need, as chances are there's a much better, cleaner and more scalable way to do what you need.

Comment: If your creating a "stick figure" you should be binding a ObservableCollection of points to a list of Lines in your UI

Comment: Setting aside the fact that there are cleaner ways to accomplish this, if you're using .net 4.5, changing your method to async and using `await Task.Delay(100)` instead of `Thread.Sleep(100)` is a quick fix to get things updating.

Comment: @HighCore you can find a screenshot at this link: http://tinypic.com/r/10893xz/6 I have recordings that are 60 frames long and for each frame I have 40 values. 20 points with an X and a Y value for each point. I need to see 2 different recordings next to each other.

Answer (score 0):

You cant see any update on the GUI, because your single thread app is using the GUI thread to loop around. A solution could be using a timer, or a secondary thread.

Comment: And how should I do this with a timer or a secondary thread? I'm just a beginning programmer.